# Keeping an overflowing div centered in parent's viewport when upscaling/downscaling it

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

I am building a simple map system with features similar to Google Map's : click and drag to scroll the map, zoom in/out, recenter.

For this, I use a mapContainer as a viewport for the map (since it only takes a portion of the screen). This mapContainer contains a div named map, which is bigger than the mapContainer, and absolutely positioned (because it's top and left properties are modified as the user drags and scrolls the map).
The simplified code looks like this :

```
<div id="mapContainer">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#mapContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

I am however encountering a problem with the zoom in/out feature. To achieve that, I simply apply a scale transformation on the map div (zoomed out: 0.65, zoomed in: 1). The problem is, I would like to keep the map div **centered in the mapContainer viewport** when unzooming it.
Because the position of the map div can be changed freely, it will often look like the map zooms out and goes away to the left, or top, or bottom, or right, depending on where it is (its left and top properties) within the mapContainer viewport.

The only possibility I see is to readjust the top and left properties of the map div after it has been downscaled to 0.65, but idk how really.

I've been banging my head on this for two days now, and though I'm sure it all comes down to getBoundingClientRect() calculations in the end, I have yet to solve this problem.

I tried using getBoundingClientRect() calculations, without a lot of success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.